# Want to generate picture of all the algebraic integers for all the polynomials of a given degree

Tags: polynomials

So I'm looking for a function that takes in the degree of the polynomial and the range of coefficients from -c to c, and outputs a list of all the monic polynomials of that degree and with coefficients in that range.

I already have code to numerically compute the roots and plot in the complex plane, I just need a way to compute this list. I haven't been able to find previously posted code to do this task on stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

`toMonicpol[lis_] := 
 x^(Length[lis]) + Dot[lis, Table[x^r, {r, 0, Length[lis] - 1}]]`

`pols[deg_, c_] := Map[toMonicpol[#] &, Tuples[Range[-c, c], deg]]`

`pols[2, 3]`

`{-3 - 3 x + x^2, -3 - 2 x + x^2, -3 - x + x^2, -3 + x^2, -3 +
   x + x^2, -3 + 2 x + x^2, -3 + 3 x + x^2, -2 - 3 x + x^2, -2 - 2 x +
   x^2, -2 - x + x^2, -2 + x^2, -2 + x + x^2, -2 + 2 x + x^2, -2 + 
  3 x + x^2, -1 - 3 x + x^2, -1 - 2 x + x^2, -1 - x + x^2, -1 + 
  x^2, -1 + x + x^2, -1 + 2 x + x^2, -1 + 3 x + x^2, -3 x + 
  x^2, -2 x + x^2, -x + x^2, x^2, x + x^2, 2 x + x^2, 3 x + x^2, 
 1 - 3 x + x^2, 1 - 2 x + x^2, 1 - x + x^2, 1 + x^2, 1 + x + x^2, 
 1 + 2 x + x^2, 1 + 3 x + x^2, 2 - 3 x + x^2, 2 - 2 x + x^2, 
 2 - x + x^2, 2 + x^2, 2 + x + x^2, 2 + 2 x + x^2, 2 + 3 x + x^2, 
 3 - 3 x + x^2, 3 - 2 x + x^2, 3 - x + x^2, 3 + x^2, 3 + x + x^2, 
 3 + 2 x + x^2, 3 + 3 x + x^2}`

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can use `FromDigits[{1, a, b, c}, x]` to get a polynomial of degree `Length[{a,b,c}]` in `x` with leading coefficient `1`:

```
 Expand @ FromDigits[{1, a, b, c}, x]
```

> c + b x + a x^2 + x^3

Using `Tuples[Range[-c,c], deg]`, as in ulvi's answer, to generate all tuples (i.e., all possible non-leading coefficients in a polynomial with degree `deg`), and  `Prepend`ing  each tuple with `1`, we can use `FromDigits` on each list to get the desired list of monic polynomials:

```
mp[d_, c_] := Expand @ FromDigits[Prepend[#, 1], x] & /@ Tuples[Range[-c, c], d];
```

This gives the same list of polynomials as ulvi's `pols`:

```
Sort[mp[2, 3] ] == Sort[pols[2, 3]]
```

> True